# Supposed A and B are sets, If C(A) ≤ B, prove C(P(A)) ≤ C(P(B))

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I only understand that if C(A) = n then C(P(A)) is 2^n and C(A) ≤ C(B) if and only if there is Bo ≤ B such as Bo ~ A which means there is bijection from A to B.

But then how am I supposed to prove C(P(A)) ≤ C(P(B))?

Comment: Hint : If $n\leq m$, then $2^n \leq 2^m$

Comment: Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type your equations

Comment: For completeness sake you need to also consider infinite sets.

Comment: Excuse me, @JMoravitz but could you explain to me how exactly to prove A ≤ B for infinite sets?